# oracle and sql server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, data-dictionary

I have an application management analyzes that revolves around a sql server 2008 database. when I connect to the database via the Talend ETL tool I can not know which tables contain the fields I need. my question there has there a possibility to extract the sql queries that propagate << >> in the database when I do a data entry in the database. the base is a little high, I can not distinguish the tables and fields that I need. That there 's no descriptive (of specifications) of the base. (It is old)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. If English isn't your native language, you might try to get some help rephrasing it so that it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> "has there a possibility to extract the sql queries that propagate << >> in the database "

You can find the text of queries in database views, specifically the SQL_TEXT and 
SQL_FULLTEXT columns of the V$SQL view.    The view has other useful columns which will help you understand the pattern of SQL usage in your database; for instance, you can pick out which queries are run the most often.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_3043.htm#sthref3700).

It's not a view which is normally available to regular users so you may need DBA access to see this view.